# unable to download flyway 3.2.1

Tags: linux, command-line, download, flyway

I am not able to download flyway 3.2.1 command tool version. it is giving me an error incomplete download.

http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/flyway-commandline-3.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try again. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded the latest version.